# How to import from html5lib.sanitizer

Tags: python, html5lib, sanitizer

I am trying to import module `HTMLSanitizerMixin` from module `html5lib.sanitizer`  in Python. After searching the web, I see that in the update for `html5lib` they removed the `sanitizer` package, but I can't seem to get it now even when I try to import it from the new location.

Comment: ...the new location? What do you mean?

Comment: "Get rid of the sanitizer package. Merge sanitizer.sanitize into the sanitizer.htmlsanitizer module and move that to sanitizer. This means anyone who used sanitizer.sanitize or sanitizer.HTMLSanitizer needs no code changes". I took it form here:https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html5lib

Comment: @Danielyaory What are you actually trying to do? Why are you wanting to import it?

Answer (score 0):

Something has changed since 1.0.

```
sudo pip install html5lib==0.90
```